# fablinker.php:343 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i am getting this error in the console when I try to call a function on click. I looked up all the other solution on stack such as jquery duplication and that but does not seem to be working ,

Any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

dialog is part of jQueryUI, you need to load that, too, not just jQuery.